# Teradata SQL select string of multiple capital letters in a text field

Tags: sql, teradata

Any help would be much appreciated on figuring out how to identify Acronyms within a text field that has mixed upper and lower case letters.
For example, we might have 
"*we used the BBQ sauce on the Chicken*"
I need my query to SELECT "BBQ" and nothing else in the cell.
There could be multiple capitalized string per row
The output should include the uppcase string.

Any ideas are much appreciated!!

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to be able to accomplish this unless you are looking for a specific set of acronyms. How would you determine the difference between "was" (past tense of to be) vs. WAS (Website Analytics Software)?

Comment: Yes, that's my concern. I'm actually creating data quality checks for a portions of a form with long text responses. It's a fairly small number so the folks currently scanning for acronyms manually will instead (hopefully) scan a list of possible acronyms generated by this query. There's also the issue of acceptable acronyms like VP or ID. So any ideas on how to generate an imperfect list would be awesome :). Thanks!!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you actually using?

Comment: Teradata SQL- is that what you mean?

Comment: What do you want to do in the case that you have multiple acronyms in a sentence? ie "What insurance coverage did you select PPO or HMO?" Also, what do you need to account for '.' periods? Are you expecting to have varchar types or text?

Comment: @user8232474 I removed the TSQL tag as it doesn't apply to your question. +1 for a good question.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be kind of ugly. I tried to use REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE to just pull out the all caps words, but couldn't make it work.

I would do it by first using `strtok_split_to_table`, so each word will end up in it's own row.

First, some dummy data:

```
create volatile table vt 
(id integer,
col1 varchar(20))
on commit preserve rows;

insert into vt
values (1,'foo BAR');

insert into vt
values (2,'fooBAR');

insert into vt
values(3,'blah FOO FOO blah');
```

We can use strtok_split_to_table on this:

```
select
t.*
from table
(strtok_split_to_table(vt.id ,vt.col1,' ')
returns
(tok_key integer 
,tok_num INTEGER
,tok_value VARCHAR(30)
)) AS t
```

That will split each value into separate rows, using a space as a delimiter.

Finally, we can compare each of those values to that value in upper case:

```
select
vt.id,
vt.col1,
tok_key,
tok_num,
tok_value,
case when upper(t.tok_value) = t.tok_value (CASESPECIFIC) then tok_value else '0' end
from
(
select
t.*
from table
(strtok_split_to_table(vt.id ,vt.col1,' ')
returns
(tok_key integer 
,tok_num INTEGER
,tok_value VARCHAR(30)
)) AS t
) t
inner join vt
    on t.tok_key = vt.id
order by id,tok_num
```

Taking our lovely sample data, you'll get:

```
+----+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| id |       col1        | tok_key | tok_num | tok_value | TEST_OUTPUT |
+----+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | foo BAR           |       1 |       1 | foo       | 0           |
|  1 | foo BAR           |       1 |       2 | BAR       | BAR         |
|  2 | fooBAR            |       2 |       1 | fooBAR    | 0           |
|  3 | blah FOO FOO blah |       3 |       1 | blah      | 0           |
|  3 | blah FOO FOO blah |       3 |       2 | FOO       | FOO         |
|  3 | blah FOO FOO blah |       3 |       3 | FOO       | FOO         |
|  3 | blah FOO FOO blah |       3 |       4 | blah      | 0           |
+----+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining acronyms as all uppercase words with 2 to 5 characters with a `'\b[A-Z]{2,5}\b'` regex:

```
WITH cte AS
 ( -- using @Andrew's Volatile Table 
   SELECT * 
   FROM vt
   -- only rows containing acronyms
   WHERE RegExp_Similar(col1, '.*\b[A-Z]{2,5}\b.*') = 1 
 )
SELECT
   outkey,
   tokenNum,
   CAST(RegExp_Substr(Token, '[A-Z]*') AS VARCHAR(5)) AS acronym -- 1st uppercase word 
   --,token
FROM TABLE
    ( RegExp_Split_To_Table
        ( cte.id,
          cte.col1,

             -- split before an acronym, might include additional characters after
             -- [^A-Z]*? = any number of non uppercase letters (removed)
             -- (?= ) = negative lookahead, i.e. check, but don't remove
          '[^A-Z]*?(?=\b[A-Z]{2,5}\b)',

          '' -- defaults to case sensitive
        ) RETURNS
            ( outKey INT,
              TokenNum INT,
              Token VARCHAR(30000) -- adjust to match the size of your input column 
            )
    ) AS t
WHERE acronym <> ''
```

Comment: Depending on the version of Teradata this may not run though.  I'm on 14.10, and the match option is required for `regexp_substr` .  Additionally, after making that change, all I'm getting back from regexp_split_to_table is the first letter of each upper case "word".

Comment: @Andrew: Strange, works fine on 15 & 15.10, they apparently fixed some issues.

Comment: Maybe that's why I've had so much trouble with regexp_split_to_table then.  Hopefully we'll upgrade soon.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what are you trying to do but I thing you have many options. I.e.:

**Option 1)** check if the acronym (like BBQ) exist in the string (basic syntax)

```
SELECT CHARINDEX ('BBQ',@string)
```

In this case you would need a table of all know acronyms you want to check for and then loop through each of them to see if there is a match for your string and then return the acronym.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100)
SET @string = 'we used the BBQ sauce on the Chicken'

create table : [acrs]
--+--- acronym-----+
--+    BBQ         +
--+    IBM         +
--+    AMD         +
--+    ETC         +
--+----------------+

SELECT acronym FROM [acrs] WHERE CHARINDEX ([acronym], @string ) > 0)
```

This should return : 'BBQ'

**Option 2)** load up all the upper case characters into a temp table etc. for further logic and processing. I think you could use something like this...

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100)
SET @string = 'we used the BBQ sauce on the Chicken'

-- make table of all Upper case letters and process individually
;WITH cte_loop(position, acrn)
 AS (
        SELECT 1, SUBSTRING(@string, 1, 1)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT position + 1, SUBSTRING(@string, position + 1, 1)
        FROM cte_loop
        WHERE position < LEN(@string) 
 )
SELECT position, acrn, ascii(acrn) AS [ascii]
FROM cte_loop
WHERE ascii(acrn) > 64 AND ascii(acrn) < 91 -- see the ASCII table for all codes
```

**This would return table like this:**

[image]